# How to display paragraph <p> some paragraph </p> inside TextView without showing <p>?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just want to know how I need to format android.widget.TextView text so that

```
  <p> does not show </p>  // the <p> symbol should not be shown.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From Html class. You can use,

```
Html.FromHtml(<Html String>);
```

Also type of tags are supported please look at this..

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

**Example:**

```
String htmlString = "<p> does not show </p>";
textView.setText(Html.FromHtml(htmlString));
```

Comment: to know what type is Html, and to understand why this question is not relevant, please read the documentation.

Comment: ok. Also I notice that string is not line formatted for the TextView. It returns a spannable. Is there any way to take the content and display so that line is formatted.

Comment: For more details look at this document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: The lines are not event when there is a paragraph within a TextView is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOUR STRING"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a string as:

```
<resource>
    <string name="your_string">This is an <p>paragraph</p> text demo for TextView.</string>
</resources>
```